# Change CRS of layer, but keep location on map?

Tags: qgis, postgis, pyqgis, postgresql

I have some layers I've inherited. They are all polygons. Most of them are in the correct CRS, which is EPSG 4326. Some of them are not, they are in EPSG 26918. They were natively created this way.

All the layers show on the map where they belong, I am assuming because the layers with the incorrect CRS are reprojected on the fly by QGIS.

I can change the CRS of the incorrect layers to EPSG 4326, but naturally, they now appear far away from where they should be on the map.

I feel like there must be an obvious answer I am missing here. 
Is there an easy way to change the CRS of these layers from 26918 to 4326, and keep the location of the objects where they belong on the map?

A solution in QGIS (including pyqgis) or PostgreSQL would be great!

Comment: you have to export the layers with 26918 to 4326 with right mouse click and then export->save features as and then choose the crs to the desired one. this will produce a new dataset with the choosen projection.

Comment: you said it yourself..."reproject"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to reproject your layer - there are at least two possibilities: option 1, as eurojam suggested: export the layer. Option 2: in the toolbox, search for reproject layer - there is a function named like that. Use it to reproject your layer.

Comment: of course! such an easy answer...